# checking checkbox.name during xml parsing so that i do not duplicate a checkbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xml-parsing

I need to parse a xml document with many elements with their element's attribute value to create new checkbox with the attribute value as the name of the checkbox. In my application I've already hard coded some of these attribute value into checkboxes. Therefore my question is, is there a way for me to check if these have already been created? If yes, I will not do anything. If no, I will then create new checkbox.

Here is an example of an XML document to be parsed:

```
<target name="number1" if="nameofcheckbox1">
...
</target>
<target name="number2" if="nameofcheckbox2">
...
</target>
```

In the above example, I've already hard coded a checkbox and called it: nameofcheckbox1CheckBox. Then i will parse this document and new checkbox will be created for the "number2". It will be called nameofcheckbox2CheckBox. Hence, I will need something here to make sure that i do not duplicate another checkbox called nameofcheckbox1CheckBox. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
bool checkbox1Exists = ControlExists("nameofcheckbox1");
bool checkbox2Exists = ControlExists("nameofcheckbox2");

private bool ControlExists(string name)
{
    return FindName(name) != null;
}
```

Comment: hi wallstreet, i have more than 50 checkboxes to check against...there is a lot to hard code. so every time a new checkbox is created, i have to hard code it again so that the next time it will be checked against. is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean you have to hard code? I though you created checkboxes dynamically from some xml data? Before creating a checkbox, check if the checkbox exists using the provided ControlExists function.

Comment: Better solution is hard to suggest since we don't know what you are trying to do. If you need to display 50 checkboxes I would just have an ItemsControl with a checkbox as its itemtemplate and data bind the ItemsControl's ItemsSource to your xml data. If your xml data is not directly bindable (maybe needs some data scrubbing), I would use a VM, load the xml, scrub the data and populate some collection property you can easily bind to.